# SQL join multiple "id" columns from a single row to another table

Tags: mysql, join

Apologies if this has been asked but I've tried searching and haven't come across anything similar. I have a two tables in a MySQL database. Athletes and Teams

The athletes table contains the following columns:

- athleteID
- firstName
- lastName

and the Teams table consists of:

- teamID
- athleteID_1
- athleteID_2
- athleteID_3
- athleteID_4

Given a teamID, I would like to retrieve the firstName, lastName, and athleteID of all the athletes on the team.

Currently, I am doing five queries

```
SELECT athleteID_1, athleteID_2, athleteID_3, athleteID_4 FROM Teams WHERE teamID=3
```

Then using a for loop in PHP to run the following query four times (once for each athleteID:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName from Athletes where athleteID=$athlete_id_n
```

I would like to end up with a four arrays, each with two entries (firstName and lastName).

Comment: Do you want a single record with all names or a record for each athlete by team?

Comment: I would like a record for each athlete on the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a union. [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c59f85/1)

```
select * from (
  select t.teamID, a1.firstName, a1.LastName, 1 as AthleteNumber from teams t
  inner join athletes a1 on a1.athleteID = t.athleteID_1
  union
  select t.teamID, a2.firstName, a2.LastName, 2 as AthleteNumber from teams t
  inner join athletes a2 on a2.athleteID = t.athleteID_2
  union
  select t.teamID, a3.firstName, a3.LastName, 3 as AthleteNumber from teams t
  inner join athletes a3 on a3.athleteID = t.athleteID_3
  union
  select t.teamID, a4.firstName, a4.LastName, 4 as AthleteNumber from teams t
  inner join athletes a4 on a4.athleteID = t.athleteID_4
) s
order by teamID, AthleteNumber
;
```

Comment: Very clever! If I want to filter by Team, where would the WHERE go?

Comment: @KevinMorse I would put the `where` right before the `order by` clause.

Comment: If I restrict to a single Team, I no longer need the `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

A 1:many relationship should *not* be done via multiple columns.

Table `Athletes` should include a `team_id` column.

Table `Teams` should not include any mention of athletes.

Comment: Athletes can be on multiple teams. Teams can ONLY have four athletes.

Comment: Then consider a many:many table.  What sport has 4?

Comment: Actual seven athletes but it was shorter to do the example with only four ;)

Comment: What do you mean many:many table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
SELECT teamID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(athletes.firstName, ' ', athletes.lastName)) athletes
FROM teams, athletes
WHERE athletes.athleteID IN (teams.athleteID_1, teams.athleteID_2, teams.athleteID_3, teams.athleteID_4)
GROUP BY teamID
```

is enough?

Comment: This query might help in another section of the program!